# Finding gaps in sequence of numbers

Tags: c++, stl

I have a std::vector containing a handful of numbers, which are not in any particular order, and may or may not have gaps between the numbers - for example, I may have { 1,2,3, 6 } or { 2,8,4,6 } or { 1, 9, 5, 2 }, etc.

I'd like a simple way to look at this vector and say 'give me the lowest number >= 1 which does *not* appear in the vector'.  So,

for the three examples above, the answers would be 4, 1 and 3 respectively.

It's not performance critical, and the list is short so there aren't any issues about copying the list and sorting it, for example.

I am not really stuck for a way to do this, but my STL skills are seriously atrophied and I can feel that I'm about to do something inelegant - I would be interested to see what other people came up with.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The checked answer uses < for comparison. != is much simpler:

```
int find_gap(std::vector<int> vec) {
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    int next = 1;
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it) {
        if (*it != next) return next;
       ++next;
    }
    return next;
}

find_gap(1,2,4,5) = 3
find_gap(2) = 1
find_gap(1,2,3) = 4
```

I'm not passing a reference to the vector since a) he said time doesn't matter and b) so I don't change the order of the original vector.

Answer (score 12):

The standard algorithm you are looking for is **[std::adjacent_find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find)**.

Here is a solution that also uses a lambda to make the predicate clean:

```
int first_gap( std::vector<int> vec )
{
  // Handle the special case of an empty vector.  Return 1.
  if( vec.empty() )
    return 1;

  // Sort the vector
  std::sort( vec.begin(), vec.end() );

  // Find the first adjacent pair that differ by more than 1.
  auto i = std::adjacent_find( vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](int l, int r){return l+1<r;} );

  // Handle the special case of no gaps.  Return the last value + 1.
  if ( i == vec.end() )
    --i;

  return 1 + *i;
}
```

Comment: In many ways that's exactly what I asked for.  I'm going to leave a slightly less STL-like version selected because I'm on a bit of a downer about endless predicate functions at the moment.  Roll-on C++ lambdas.

Comment: The question has a well-defined answer for empty vectors. In an empty vector, the smallest integer >= 1 that does not appear in the vector is 1. In STL terms: we're looking for the smallest N>=1 such that find(begin,end,N)==end.

Answer (score 5):

Sorting the list and then doing a linear search seems the simplest solution.  Depending on the expected composition of the lists you could use a less general purpose sorting algorithm, and if you implement the sort yourself you could keep track of data during the sort that could be used to speed up (or eliminate entirely) the search step.  I do not think there is any particularly elegant solution to this problem

Answer (score 4):

You could allocate a bit vector (of the same length as the input vector), initialize it to zero, then mark all indices that occur (note that numbers larger than the length can be ignored).  Then, return the first unmarked index (or the length if all indices are marked, which only happens if all indices occur exactly once in the input vector).

This should be asymptotically faster than sort and search.  It will use more memory than sorting if you are allowed to destroy the original, but less memory than sorting if you must preserve the original.

Comment: clever solution

Comment: rough implementation: https://ideone.com/5C1iQ3, there is a slight modification to always include 0 in the bit vector

Answer (score 2):

Sort-n-search:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
int lowest = 1;
for(size_t ii = 1; ii < vec.size(); ++ii)
{
    if (vec[ii - 1] + 1 < vec[ii])
    {
        lowest = (vec[ii - 1] + 1);
        break;
    }
}

/* 1, 2, ..., N case */
if (lowest == vec[0]) lowest = (*vec.back()) + 1;
```

Iterators could be used with just as clear intent as [showcased in @joe_mucchiello's (*ed: better*) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379383/finding-gaps-in-sequence-of-numbers#379507).

Comment: OK, thanks very much.  I've just done something like this, but with iterators and handling the end case as well.

Comment: {1,2,3,4} should return 5 not 1. This code accounts for the edge condition at the beginning, but not at the end.

Comment: @Will and @Greg, fixed. Iterators are left as an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: You should just be comparing against lowest. You always know what the next value should be. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you do a bubble sort (you know... the one that they teach you first and then tell you to never use again...), you will be able to spot the first gap early in the sorting process, so you can stop there.  That should give you the fastest overall time.

Comment: Good observation. I wonder if a k-th smallest algorithm could also be adapted, or an nlogn sort?

Comment: Nice!  There actually is a use for it.

Comment: Only if the first gap is a fairly low number.  In the worst case, all the numbers from [1..size] occur, and your runtime will be O(size^2)

Comment: O() notation is by definition the worst case.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's my 2 cents.  Assume you've got a vector of length N.

1. If N<=2 you can check directly
2. First, use min_element to get the smallest element, remember it as emin
3. Call nth_element to get the element at N/2, call it ehalf
4. If ehalf != emin+N/2 there's a gap to the left, apply this method recursively there by calling nth_element on the whole array but asking for element N/4.  Otherwise, recurse on the right asking for element 3*N/4.

This should be slightly better than sorting completely up front.

Comment: Your assumption that emin+N/2 is going to be at index N/2 presumes that the array is already sorted.

Comment: Um, no.  I didn't presume that.  I called nth_element to find just which element WOULD be there in sorted order.  nth_element uses the median-find algorithm.  There *is* and optimization possible:  you can recurse on half the array (nth_element partitions).

Comment: And by the way:  this is *faster* than sort-n-search on average if you do optimize by only recursively processing the necessary half of the array.

Comment: See my answer for a possible implementation.

Answer (score 1):

you could go with something like....

```
struct InSequence
{
    int _current;   bool insequence;
    InSequence() : _current(1), insequence(true){}
    bool operator()(int x) {         
        insequence = insequence ? (x == _current) : false;  
        _current++; 
        return insequence;
    }
};

int first_not_in_sequence(std::vector<int>& v)
{
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    return 1+std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(),InSequence());
}
```

Comment: You `insequence` test in op() is overly complicated. You can write it much simpler and clearer: `insequence = insequence && x == _current;`. In general, `bool1 ? bool2 : bool3` can always be written as `bool1 && bool2 || bool3` (but it's not always more readable).

Comment: +1 for showing Kristo the STLish way to do this using a functor with state... Though you shouldn't use a lead underscore to mark local variables as those names are reserved for the compiler, int current_; has the same impact and it's guaranteed not to have conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

**A possible implementation of Thomas Kammeyer's answer**

I found Thomas' approach really smart and useful - since some of us dream in code and I find the actual implementation a bit tricky I wanted to provide some ready-to-use code.

The solution presented here is as generic as possible:

- No assumption is made on the type of container or range except their iterators must meet the requirements of ValueSwappable and RandomAccessIterator (due to partial sorting with `nth_element`)
- Any number type can be used - the required traits are outlined below

Another improvement I think is that a no-gap condition can be checked early: since we have to scan for the minimum anyway we can also scan for the maximum at the same time and then determine whether the number range even contains a gap worth finding.

Last but not least the same recursive approach can be adapted for sorted ranges! If you encode in a template value parameter whether the range is already sorted, you can simply skip the partial sorting plus make determining minimum/maximum elements a no-op.

```c++
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>

// number type must be:
// * arithmetic
//   * subtractable (a - b)
//   * divisible by 2 (a / 2)
// * incrementable (++a)
// * less-than-comparable (a < b)
// * default-constructible (A{})
// * copy-constructible
// * value-constructible (A(n))
// * unsigned or number range must only contain values >0

/** Find lowest gap value in a range */
template<typename Range>
typename std::remove_reference_t<Range>::value_type
lowest_gap_value_unsorted(Range&& r)
{
    static_assert(!std::is_lvalue_reference_v<Range> && !std::is_const_v<Range>, "lowest_gap_value_unsorted requires a modifiable copy of the passed range");

    return lowest_gap_value_unsorted(std::begin(r), std::end(r), std::size(r));
}

/** Find lowest gap value in a range with specified size */
template<typename Range>
typename std::remove_reference_t<Range>::value_type
lowest_gap_value_unsorted(Range&& r, std::size_t N)
{
    static_assert(!std::is_lvalue_reference_v<Range> && !std::is_const_v<Range>, "lowest_gap_value_unsorted requires a modifiable copy of the passed range");

    return lowest_gap_value_unsorted(std::begin(r), std::end(r), N);
}

/** Find lowest gap value in an iterator range */
template<typename Iterator>
typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type
lowest_gap_value_unsorted(Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    return lowest_gap_value_unsorted(first, last, std::distance(first, last));
}

/** Find lowest gap value in an iterator range with specified size */

template<typename Iterator>
typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type
lowest_gap_value(Iterator first, Iterator last, std::size_t N)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type Number;

    if (bool empty = last == first)
        return increment(Number{});

    Iterator minElem, maxElem;
    std::tie(minElem, maxElem) = std::minmax_element(first, last);

    if (bool contains0 = !(Number{} < *minElem))
        throw std::logic_error("Number range must not contain 0");

    if (bool missing1st = increment(Number{}) < *minElem)
        return increment(Number{});

    if (bool containsNoGap = !(Number(N) < increment(*maxElem - *minElem)))
        return increment(*maxElem);

    return lowest_gap_value_unsorted_recursive(first, last, N, *minElem);
}

template<typename Iterator>
typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type
lowest_gap_value_unsorted_recursive(Iterator first, Iterator last, std::size_t N, typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type minValue)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type Number;

    if (N == 1)
        return ++minValue;
    if (N == 2)
    {
        // determine greater of the 2 remaining elements
        Number maxValue = !(minValue < *first) ? *std::next(first) : *first;
        if (bool gap = ++minValue < maxValue)
            return minValue;
        else
            return ++maxValue;
    }

    Iterator medianElem = std::next(first, N / 2);
    // sort partially
    std::nth_element(first, medianElem, last);

    if (bool gapInLowerHalf = (Number(N) / 2 < *medianElem - minValue))
        return lowest_gap_value_unsorted_recursive(first, medianElem, N / 2, minValue);
    else
        return lowest_gap_value_unsorted_recursive(medianElem, last, N / 2 + N % 2, *medianElem);
};

template<typename T>
T increment(T v)
{
    return ++v;
}
```